# python exercise help space in for loop

Tags: python

I am learning python here is an example code

```
girls = ['alice','bernice','clarice']
boys = ['chris','arnold','bob']
letterGirls = {}
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
  print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

I get following error

```
 File "<stdin>", line 3
    print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

1) I want to resolve above error and
2) I want to know how to write code blocs within for loops in python
  for example in above example I checked on terminal if I do not leave white space below the first for line then the syntax is wrong I am not clear as how to give spaces in for loop code blocks in python is there some thing to leave spaces in python

```
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
  print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

**UPDATE**
 based on suggestions below I updated the code print statement is outside the for loop in the example given so I updated the program on my ubuntu terminal

```
girls = ['alice','bernice','clarice']
boys = ['chris','arnold','bob']
letterGirls = {}
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

but I still get an error with above code

```
print[b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

since I am writing program on terminal here is exactly how my terminal looks like

```
@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> girls = ['alice','bernice','clarice']
>>> boys = ['chris','arnold','bob']
>>> letterGirls = {}
>>> for girl in girls:
...     letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
... print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print[b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code of the same level should be using the same indent, so 'for' statement and 'print' should be in one column(the same indent). Suggested way is to use 4 spaces to indent level from level. Change your code to:

```
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

My suggestion for you is to read more in [PEP8 guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) this will make your life easier

Comment: so if I need to use a print statement within a for block that means I need to have 4 spaces before it

Comment: @RegisteredUser if you need to place it inside of 'for' than it need to be placed 4 spaces + 'for' indent if any. So if 'for' starts from begin of line than print statement will have 4 spaces from begin of line in case when for is inside of function and already have 4 spaces indent than print will have 4+4=8 spaces.And so on

Comment: It's better to create new question, but the problem is in letterGirls[b[0]] - erros simply saying you that there is no such key. Check what you have inside of dictionary using print statements and it will help you to figure out your problem now

Answer (score -1):

1)you have wrong indents in "print" statement, make sure you indent 4 spaces for same level block in Python . In this case, you shouldn't indent before 'print' .

```
girls = ['alice','bernice','clarice']
boys = ['chris','arnold','bob']
letterGirls = {}
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

output:

```
['chris+clarice', 'arnold+alice', 'bob+bernice']
```

2) if you want to create a block statements in a loop , make sure all statements have same indent level.

```
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
    print "This is in the loop"
print "This is not in the loop"
```

Comment: Hmmm I get your point and I want to see the output which you mentioned but I still get error I have updated the question

Answer (score -1):

If you want print statement **OUTSIDE** the loop:

```
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

If you want print statement **INSIDE** the loop:

```
for girl in girls:
    letterGirls.setdefault(girl[0],[]).append(girl)
    print [b+'+'+g for b in boys for g in letterGirls[b[0]]]
```

The indentation must align. [Read more here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id9). You should use 4 spaces per indentation level.

for example if you want another level in your code :

```
for ():
    print x
    for():
        print x
```

For every indentation level, the spaces must be 4.

PS. This is what you must apply even if you use other command like while loop or if/else condition.